# Selecting First Tuple in from numerous tuples python

Tags: python, tuples

My python code gives the following output:

```
(u'I See Fire', ' ', u'Ed Sheeran', ' ', u'4456cdba-a795-4910-9753-ad3f400bba85', ' ', 0.939346)
(u'I See Fire', ' ', u'Ed Sheeran', ' ', u'7d3253d7-c3ad-4c37-8318-6d3e9788e91e', ' ', 0.939346)
(u'I See Fire (Kygo Remix)', ' ', u'Kygo; Ed Sheeran', ' ', u'88353ad4-aff6-421d-a4be-d07791271d71', ' ', 0.939346)
```

The format is (artist,title,md-id ,score). I want to pick the first tuple from this. I have tried using `artist[0]`, `title[0]`, etc.

Please let me know how to pick the top entry or the nth entry from the top.

Comment: artist[0], title[0] - what are those list? post them

Comment: What do you mean *"gives the following output"*? Is it printing the tuples? Yielding them? Returning a list of them?

Comment: Kind of hard to answer without knowing a) what the *input* is nor b) what the expected output is nor c) what the *code* is, nor even d) what you are trying to do.

Comment: You can use `zip` function to get an iterable contain the columns and if you just want the first column in python3 you can use `next` and `zip`:

    `next(zip(rows))`

and in python 2 you can use :

   `from itertools import izip
   next(izip(rows))`

Comment: I am using acoustid to get the metadata from an mp3 file. I have tried printing the output in the following way: for score,rid,artist,title in result:
...    print(artist," " , title, " " , rid , " " , score). The output is what I have given in the question. Apologies for the ambiguity

Answer (score 0):

Given your output:

```
output1 = (u'I See Fire', ' ', u'Ed Sheeran', ' ', u'4456cdba-a795-4910-9753-ad3f400bba85', ' ', 0.939346)
output2 = (u'I See Fire', ' ', u'Ed Sheeran', ' ', u'7d3253d7-c3ad-4c37-8318-6d3e9788e91e', ' ', 0.939346)
output3 = (u'I See Fire (Kygo Remix)', ' ', u'Kygo; Ed Sheeran', ' ', u'88353ad4-aff6-421d-a4be-d07791271d71', ' ', 0.939346)
```

You can pull just `(u'I See Fire', ' ', u'Ed Sheeran')` by the statement:

```
output1[0:3]
```

If you output is a tuple of tuples:

```
output = ((u'I See Fire', ' ', u'Ed Sheeran', ' ', u'4456cdba-a795-4910-9753-ad3f400bba85', ' ', 0.939346),(u'I See Fire', ' ', u'Ed Sheeran', ' ', u'7d3253d7-c3ad-4c37-8318-6d3e9788e91e', ' ', 0.939346),(u'I See Fire (Kygo Remix)', ' ', u'Kygo; Ed Sheeran', ' ', u'88353ad4-aff6-421d-a4be-d07791271d71', ' ', 0.939346))
```

You can pull just `(u'I See Fire (Kygo Remix)', ' ', u'Kygo; Ed Sheeran')` with the statement:

```
output[2][0:3]
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Append the output to a list and then slice the first entry

instead of:

```
print(output)
```

do:

```
alist = []
for output in someresultfromsomegenerator:
    alist.append(output)
print(alist[0])
```

if your output is the result from a function you could do something like:

```
result = thisfunctionreturnstheoutput()[0]
print(result)
```

Hope this helps.